# Finding the number of different dict elements in a list of dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been given a list of dicts, suppose

```
L = [
  {'color':'R', 'rank':2},
  {'color':'G', 'rank':1},
  {'color':'G', 'rank':2}, 
  {'color':'R', 'rank':2}, 
  {'color':'Y', 'rank':4}, 
  {'color':'G', 'rank':2}
]
```

I need to find the find the count of different dict items in the list, i.e. `{'color':'R', 'rank':2}` has count 2, `{'color':'G', 'rank':2}` has count 2 etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an attempt at you solving the problem before asking the question. Anyways, to answer your question from a simple google search would give you `L.count({"color": "R", "rank": 2})`.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to do this. I like using pandas here, because a list of dicts can easily be represented as a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(L).groupby(["color", "rank"]).size()
```

Another way is:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([f"{d['color']}_{d['rank']}" for d in L])
>>> Counter({'R_2': 2, 'G_1': 1, 'G_2': 2, 'Y_4': 1})
```

Dicts are not hashable, so we need to convert the dict to something hashable like a string, hence the f-string.

Answer (score 0):

I will try:

```
x = dict()
for element in L:
  if element['color'] in x:
    x[element['color']]+=1
  else:
    x[element['color']]=1
```

In `x` you should have the count.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, may I ask how can I get back the dict elements if there are 2 elements present of the same kind. In my case I want to make a new list cards = [] and append it with the dict elements in list L that occur twice, i.e.   {'color':'R', 'rank':2},   {'color':'G', 'rank':2}, should be appended to my new list cards.append(xxxx)

Comment: your code considers all the 'G' elements as same, while one is of rank 1 and the other two is of rank 2''